# Rails syntax error on updating an Object inside an if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot figure out why this is throwing a syntax error:

```
  if feeds.include? 'job'
      #when only updating one attribute use this over 'update(params)'
      broadcast.update_attribute(:jobs true)
    else
      #do nothing at the moment
  end
```

the error message is:

```
app/models/broadcast_service.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_true, expecting ')'
app/models/broadcast_service.rb:100: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

`:jobs` is a `boolean`, and i want to set its value to `true`

where `line 17 is the above`, and `line 100 is the very last line of the file`, which is an `end keyword`

Comment: Forgot a comma between `:jobs` and `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly i missed the comma in between parameters.

```
if feeds.include? 'job'
      #when only updating one attribute use this over 'update(params)'
      broadcast.update_attribute(:jobs, true)
    else
      #do nothing at the moment
  end
```

Comment: You self-answered your question. It's unlikely to be useful to anyone else (too specific). So you may just delete it.